# Cannot get value of ng-model through $scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to get the value of the ng-model when clicking a button which triggers a function to add each ng-model value to an object. When trying to get the value of `$scope.shipNameFirst`, it comes up as `undefined` in the second example.

I've read that it's better to get the value of $scope on the view rather than passing it through the stripeBtn function, so ideally I'd like to do it that way. Hopefully this makes sense.

Can someone explain why this is not working?

## Working

#### HTML

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="shipNameFirst">
  <input type="text" ng-model="shipNameLast">

  <button type="button" ng-click="stripeBtn(shipNameFirst, shipNameLast)">Checkout with Stripe</button>
```

#### Controller

```
  $scope.stripeBtn = function(shipNameFirst, shipNameLast){

    $scope.details = {
      recNameFirst: shipNameFirst,
      recNameLast: shipNameLast,
    }
  }
```

## Not Working

#### HTML

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="shipNameFirst">
  <input type="text" ng-model="shipNameLast">

  <button type="button" ng-click="stripeBtn()">Checkout with Stripe</button>
```

#### Controller

```
  $scope.stripeBtn = function(){

  console.log($scope.shipNameFirst); //logging this (with $scope) comes up as undefined

    $scope.details = {
      recNameFirst: $scope.shipNameFirst,
      recNameLast: $scope.shipNameLast,
    }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Weird, can you show us how you included the controller? Are you using controllerAs? Is this in a directive?

Comment: [Works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/tvv8y3gp/). Remember it will return undefined if you submit without putting anything in the inputs.

Comment: The code is working fine, your problem might come from other part of your app ...

Comment: @Keith Just to ensure if there is any issue with the scope being lost, can you try the below.
Change the element to ng-model="parent.shipNameFirst"
Then in the controller, add the lines below and give a try
$scope.parent = {}; console.log($scope.parent.shipNameFirst);

Comment: Your code should work. please post your whole code here so that we can check what is going wrong and why is your controller loosing its scope even though `$scope.stripeBtn` function is getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code. It's working nicely.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.stripeBtn = function(){

  console.log($scope.shipNameFirst); 

    $scope.details = {
      recNameFirst: $scope.shipNameFirst,
      recNameLast: $scope.shipNameLast,
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="shipNameFirst">
  <input type="text" ng-model="shipNameLast">

  <button type="button" ng-click="stripeBtn()">Checkout with Stripe</button>
</div>
```